# Use xlExpression with "And" in conditional format

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use VBA to give conditional formatting to my table, however my code generates error.

The code is:

```
Range("M236:P240").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
    Formula1:="=AND(<$M$241, <7)"            

Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 192
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

When I run it I get an error 5 in the line:

```
Formula1:="=AND(<$M$241,<7)"
```

I think it must be a small mistake, maybe I'm missing some parentheses or some quotation marks.

Why is this error generated?

PD: If I change it for:

```
Formula1:="=AND(M236<$M$241; M236<7)"
```

The code run, but nothing happens.

Comment: `Formula1:="=AND(M236<$M$241, M236<7)"`

Comment: @ScottCraner The same error continues to be generated. Additionally I think that even if I run there would be an error in the logic, because the condition I want to be satisfied is that each cell in the range is less than M241 AND less than 7.

Comment: Yup that is what the formula says.  Since you are applying the rule to `"M236:P240"` you would put the relative cell in the formula pointing at the upper left cell.  The conditional formatting will iterate the cell reference, as it is relative, to each of the cells in turn.

Comment: Seems to me you are missing some info also, mainly what is being done when the condition is met.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatconditions.add

Comment: @ScottCraner I edited my post by adding the complete code. If I make your change and modify the "," by ";" the code runs but nothing happens with the table.

Comment: @ScottCraner I just solved it largely thanks to you :) I'm going to publish the answer

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem. I had several errors which I mention below:

1. Thanks to @Scott Craner who mentioned that the formula should not be `Formula1:="=AND(<$M$241, <7)"` but `(M236<$M$241; M236<7)`
2. Secondly my excel for formulas does not use "," but ";".
3. My excel is in Spanish, so I shouldn't use "AND" but "Y".

Answer (score -1):

try this macro

```
Option Explicit

Sub colorize_me()
Dim Rg_To_compaire As Range
Dim My_Rg As Range
Dim Single_Range As Range
Dim My_const As Byte: My_const = 7
Set Rg_To_compaire = Range("M241")
Dim My_min#
My_min = Application.Min(Rg_To_compaire, My_const)

If Not IsNumeric(Rg_To_compaire) Then Exit Sub
Set My_Rg = Range("M236:P240")
 For Each Single_Range In My_Rg
  If IsNumeric(Single_Range) And Single_Range < My_min Then
    Single_Range.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
   Else
    Single_Range.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
 End If
   Next
End Sub
```